# Copy a div from one page and place it into another

Tags: php, html, copy

I would like to copy a div and its contents from one page and display it on another. I would like to do this so i could use the script in a CMS where an HTML editor is set.

I though about using javascript "document.getElementById" but this should be on the same page as the Div.

However I am not having any luck getting it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Would an <iframe> do what you need?

Comment: can you be please more clear about your question?

Comment: @newuser Yes the magic wand will solve everything. NOT.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this in php by using `include`.

Take the div and it's contents out of the page it's currently in and save it in it's own file, named however makes most sense given it's content. I'll use `div.html`.

Now, on the original page it was cut from, wherever you cut it out, put in:

```
<?php
    include("div.html");
?>
```

You can then use this code to include the div in any other php files you so wish.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the page in a hidden iframe and access it using jQuery:

```
div = $('#my-iframe').contents().find('div#my-div').clone();
alert($(div).html());
```

This will show an alert box with the HTML contents of the div inside the iframe.

Comment: It should work though, do you have a working page somewhere to show what you did? Probably one of the selectors is wrong.

Comment: This also requires jQuery - if you haven't got it then I'd definitely recommend picking it up at jquery.com